# Taking away white space at the bottom of my site above the footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a cornerstone page builder on my WordPress site( I am not sure if it matters), I am trying to take away some white spacing which you can see at the bottom of the page here www.simbie.com just above the footer.

I have tried everything, `body {padding:0 margin:0}` Footer margin/padding etc. It will just not go away. Does anyone have any suggestions.

Cheers

Comment: Your URL doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

Add these css to remove white spacing in home page

```
div#x-section-7 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
section#content {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Add these css to remove white spacing for other pages

```
div#footerbottom, .no.content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Happy coding..:)

Comment: It worked on the home page, these pages did not work http://simbie.com/home/about-us/  http://simbie.com/home/contact-us/.. is there any fix for that Amal? I tried to change the section number but did not work.

Comment: add this style `section#content { float: left;width: 100%; }` it will fix the issues.

Comment: Thanks, but this takes away my ability to click anything on the screen for some reason.. I cant enter text or click on buttons.

Comment: Hi,
You do not need to float or set the width. All you need to do, is remove the bottom padding from #content, which is defined in your css file. You also do not need to set margins or add further CSS to set the bottom to 0. Simply removing the bottom padding which is set in your CSS file will do this.

Comment: Hey Michael thanks for your reply, where exactly are you meaning? I have looked at my custom CSS in the customizer and the stylesheet in the backend through FTP. I have also removed all css with the id or class (content). nothing seems to be working :(